# Is it appropriate to use paired samples test for different days of the week?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data

Say we have a dataset of visitors to a mall:

```
|      Day   | Monday      | Tuesday     | Wednesday    | Thursday    | Friday
|      Group1| 195         | 220         | 245          | 213         | 285
|      Group2| 237         | 215         | 228          | 268         | 298
```

If we had to test if there was a difference between the two groups that visited the mall, would I use a two-population test, or a paired t-test?

In my opinion, it's better to use the paired t-test, because it seems that we can't say that there is independence among the different days of the week. Would my judgement be correct?

Comment: Not quite.  We use paired tests when observations come from the same individual (e.g. before/after, or when the subject serves as their own control).  Do you have data like the table you've shown?  If so, what are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: Yes the data is like the table that I've shown. I'm trying to see if there is a difference between the two groups.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but can't we think of each day as one individual? In this sense, I see no difference between this example, and the famous example with left/right tires in the same car.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the data were collected?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the exact count. There is no information on what you're asking, so it's only a guess.

Comment: My advice would be to use a chi-square test.  This will test the null hypothesis that the rows and columns are independent.

Answer (score -1):

Days are not necessarily significantly different depending on the variable to be assessed per the day of the week. For example, governments make systemic payments throughout the month, on the first, second, or third Wednesday, etc. Employers pay weekly on Fridays, etc.

As such, since there is likely a discernable pattern of distribution of funds, corresponding spending patterns, which may be of a variable of interest (maul sales figures), so I would expect an identifiable 'payday' effect. The latter may not exactly be linked to the names of the days of the week, but days close to it (a lag effect), and still likely a good predictor of daily spending patterns.

Window shopping at the maul, during working hours, is likely random, while weekend traffic is expected to be higher and may be influenced by a 
good weather factor.

One may also notice a 'Friday the 13th' effect with a discernable bump on the Saturday the 14th, depending on the variable connected to the day of the week.